# Connection with Android and Socket failed

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, connection

I want to create a connection between my node.js page and my java application

I'm trying to link this node.js page, this page :

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log("Load ...");
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
});
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('one user connected : ' + socket.id);
});
http.listen(3000 ,function(){
    console.log('Start server on port 3000');
});
```

with this java code:

My socke, this page is just to tell me if someone has joined the socket, the page is hosted on http://192.168.0.12:3000/ :

```
private Socket socket;
{
    try{
        socket = IO.socket("http://192.168.0.12:3000");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My listeners, here I'am just testing what type of errors i get:

```
    socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Errors", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Timeout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    socket.connect();
```

I always have the same error Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR.
My node.js work on network but 
My code node.js works for internet browsers but not on android, I think this from configuration but what I do not know.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

just add this in manifest:

```
 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

First,check if your android device can even access the node.js server

go the browser in your device and request the same `url`

it's maybe you cannot access the resource in the first place

Comment: I just try it's work for the browser. But not for my application.

Comment: as I remember this line shouldn't be `var http = require('http').Server(app);`
but `var http = require('http').createServer(app);
` can you check if this make any difference?

Comment: Same work for the browser. But not for my application.

Comment: what I can help you with is configurations of node.js server and the code itself.. last test to check if your server is correctly working is trying to access this url from your device which should result in a script shows in the browser `http://[your_ip]:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js` only then if succeed,your node.js server and socket.io on the server is correctly working and the problem is may be in android code

Comment: I gor the same its work for browser application and browser of my computer adress http://192.168.0.12:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js